# Change ListView textSize for Android

Tags: android, listview, text-size

I want to change listview text size, but I'm not good coder

I try all way but ıt's not possible

I want to be big textsize please help me

[[http://imgur.com/a/IPc2u][1]](https://imgur.com/a/IPc2u][1])

Here my codes;

Activicty.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="-24dp"
android:textSize="26sp"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.haziranonalti.MainActivity">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/Listview"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:dividerHeight="4px"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

---

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Listview);
    final String[] values = new String[]{"Deneme", "Deneme2", "Deneme3","Deneme4","Deneme5","Deneme6"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.activity_list_item, android.R.id.text1, values);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0) {
                Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main2Activity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myintent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 1) {
                Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main3Activity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myintent, 1);
            }
            if (position == 2) {
                Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main4Activity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myintent, 2);
            }
            if (position == 3) {
                Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main5Activity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myintent, 3);
            }
            if (position == 4) {
                Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main6Activity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myintent, 4);
            }
            if (position == 5) {
                Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main7Activity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myintent, 5);
```

Comment: if you change `android.R.layout.activity_list_item` to `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` is it enough for you?

Comment: Yes, this is enough for me. Thank you very much u are save my ass.

Comment: later ill be back to answer with more details and a way to set the font size at any size you want

Comment: Ok. I'll waiting you. Thank you again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the layout parameter to `simple_list_item_1`

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

Or you can create a new layout file in your layout directory and use this instead:

custom_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="26dp" />
```

and then use the custom layout:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.custom_layout, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's better than my old verison. Btw I have one more question how can I add search view.